# Solve for $x$ when $2^x=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know what is the value of x when:

$2^x = -1$

I guess it will be some imaginary number perhaps.

I have got the answer as $4.532360129i$. Is that precisely correct or some truncation has happened or I am wrong? What I did was as below:

$x\log2=\log(-1)$ (Taking log of both sides)
Then substituting the values I got from google.

TIA

Comment: You have that $-1=e^{i\pi+2k\pi i}$. Therefore $\ln(-1)=i\pi+2k\pi i$ are the logarithms of $-1$. From there the solutions are $x=\frac{i(2k+1)\pi}{\ln(2)+2L\pi i}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: I _highly_ doubt that that value is exact; most likely some rounding has happened.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}2^x&=-1\\x\log 2&= \log(-1) \end{aligned} $$

Since $-1=e^{i\pi+2\pi i n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ using which we get $\log(-1)$ as $i\pi+2\pi i n$ and ultimately the value of $x$ as $$x=\dfrac{i\pi+2\pi in}{\log 2} \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: $\log(2^x)\neq x\log 2$ in general.

Comment: But the change of base rule does hold in the complex plane so that we may write $$\log_22^x=\dfrac{\log(-1)}{\log 2}=\dfrac{i\pi+2\pi in}{\log 2} \text{ for } n\in\mathbb{Z}$$